# In TypeScript, how to map a field depending on if it's defined?

Tags: typescript

I have the following exampe:

```
type IsNullable<M extends {}> ={
  [k in keyof M]: M[k] extends null ? true : false
}

type X = IsNullable<{value: number|null}>
```

Intuition tells me that the type of `X` should be `{value: true}`, but in fact it's `{value: false}`. Is this a bug or is there a more correct way to do what I want?

Comment: It's the other way around: `null extends (number | null)` is `true`. The extension makes type more specialised. The more intuitive example would be `42 extends number`, the opposite is obviously nonsense.

Comment: @zerkms This is not the first time I have tripped over this word extends. I understand the logic, but my brain keeps reading extends as “makes more general”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shoud be:

```js
type IsNullable<M extends {}> ={
  [k in keyof M]: null extends M[k] ? true : false
}

type X = IsNullable<{value: number|null}>
```

as `null` is a sub-type of `number | null`

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think that's not a bug. To achieve what you want you could try this:

```
type IsNullable<M extends {}> ={
  [k in keyof M]: Extract<null, M[k]> extends null ? true : false
}

type X = IsNullable<{value: number|null}>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution appears to me to have the same exact problem: try passing `{value: number}` to `IsNullable` instead, and the result will be the same.